# Hide parent's navigation header from the nested navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm developing my first react native app. I've an issue with the nested navigations in the app.

#### I've the following navigations:

- Main App Navigator : createStackNavigator

  - Authentication Navigator : createStackNavigator
  - Bottom Bar Navigator : createBottomTabNavigator

    - Top Tab Navigator : createMaterialTopTabNavigator

      - My too nested Navigator : createStackNavigator

#### What i want ?

- I'm trying to hide the **BottomBar** & **TopTab** Navigators headers form a screen in the last **nested** navigator.

#### What I did?

- Ive tried to set the header as null in my nested nav, but thats hides the nested header not the parents headers.
- I also tried to set the parents headers as nulls, but thats hide them from all screen.

#### I need to only hide them in this nested screen. Can I change the parents headers property from my nested React Class?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't figure how to do that without using redux.

So I had to do a workaround.

I declared my Nested Navigator directly in the Main Navigator. *"in the same level as Authentication & Bottom Bar Navigations"* and set the header as null for this specific nav.

And then, navigate to that nested whenever i want.

Also, I had to add my custom icon to navigate the user back. because in our case there is no history in the new navigator in order to navigate back to.

so, i did like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
headerLeft: (
  <Icon
    name="chevron-left"
    color="#fff"
    underlayColor="#4BA6F8"
    onPress={() => {
      const backAction = NavigationActions.back();
      navigation.dispatch(backAction);
    }}
  />
),
```

});

I know this is not the real answer for my question, but at least it solved my issue.

[image]